# iPhone Linker error : Command /usr/sbin/chown failed with exit code 1

Tags: iphone, linker

I am getting a linking error when I try to archive my app. The brief description of the error is

```
`Command /usr/sbin/chown failed with exit code 1`
```

The detailed description is

```
SetOwnerAndGroup "r499908:US-ADdomain" users /Users/r499908/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/W-akvlnuynzzkjqwcmnnsmrpjpgqfs/ArchiveIntermediates/Advisor/InstallationBuildProductsLocation/Applications/W.app
    cd /Users/r499908/Desktop/Projects/JPMorganFunds-Advisor-1.4
    setenv PATH "/xcode4-gm/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/usr/bin:/xcode4-gm/usr/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin"
    /usr/sbin/chown -RH "r499908:US-AD\\domain users" /Users/r499908/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/W-akvlnuynzzkjqwcmnnsmrpjpgqfs/ArchiveIntermediates/Advisor/InstallationBuildProductsLocation/Applications/W.app

chown: US-AD\domain users: Invalid argument
Command /usr/sbin/chown failed with exit code 1
```

Is this because US-AD\domain has a backslash as opposed to front slash? If yes how do I correct this?

Answer (score 0):

The problem was the backslash.

Solved by searching for US-AD\ and changing that to admin

Answer (score 0):

changing install group to admin worked for me